# Print many copies of a pdf without using a for-loop?

Tags: linux, bash, printing

If I do

```
lp -o sides=two-sided-long-edge -n 3 -d printer8 test.pdf
```

then it prints `test.pdf` 3 times in duplex, but it first prints all the pages 1's (with page 2 on the back), then all the page 3's (with page 4 on the back) and so on.

This is annoying, as I then have to manually assemble the 3 documents afterwards.

I can solve it by

```
for f in $(seq 3); do
   lp -o sides=two-sided-long-edge -d printer8 test.pdf
done
```

but that doesn't seam like a good solution.

**Question**

Is it possible to have `lp` print one document to the end?

Comment: Related (also concerning print collation), but for different platform: [How to print multiple copies of a WORD document in normal order](https://superuser.com/q/1206578/65570) (with MS Word on Windows)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the "collate" option to enable print [collation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collation) (which is disabled by default):

`lp -n num-copies -o Collate=True filename`

[Source (CUPS documentation)](http://www.cups.org/documentation.php/options.html#OPTIONS)