# How to print multiple copies of a WORD document in normal order

Tags: microsoft-word, printing

for example, while I need to print i.e. 3 copies of i.e. 5-paged document, Microsoft word prints in such order:

1
1
1
2
2
2
.......

however, I wanted it to printed copies not such messed, but:

1
2
3
4
5
1
2
3
4
5 ......

Comment: Related (also concerning print collation), but for different platform: [Print many copies of a pdf without using a for-loop?](https://superuser.com/q/792877/65570) (with CUPS on Unix, GNU/Linux)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can choose it in the print menu with the collated/uncollated option.

[image: epic of collated print options]